# Подскажите в выборе технологии для web-приложения

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, owin

Есть .net приложение, которое работает как windows служба. При старте поднимает self host nancy owin сервис - тоесть есть какой-то графический интерфейс. Представление генерится на севрере с помощью razor-подобного движка. Есть желание переписать, заодно изучить, под современные стандарты web-разработки - использовать какой-то js движок, при этом оставить сервис функционировать с self-host сервером.
У меня такие мысли: уйти от Nancy, на сервере использовать просто технологию web-api,а js-ом уже просто дергать методы.

Начал смотреть что такое React - столкнулся с тем что React подразумевает хранение своих .jsx файлов на сервере, я так понимаю web-api не дает такой возможности - доступ к файлам в файловой систем.

Хотел спросить в чем я может заблуждаюсь и какие технологии подойдут для мой идеи? Приложение у меня довольно-таки легкое, не хотелось бы использовать какой-то выделенный web-сервер если это возможно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: я половину не понял, у Вас уже есть какая-то html-ка отдаваемая сервисом, Вы можете её изменять?

Comment: Да, могу. Она полностью генерируется на сервере.

Comment: приложения на любом веб фреймворке можно собрать в одну огромную портянку - html

Comment: Их несколько разных html-страниц, я наверное не правильно выразился, хотелось бы попробовать сделать SPA приложение, которое только дергает через rest сервис. Вот у меня и стоит вопрос в выборе технологий.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что я могу сделть react приложение только на том что получаю одну html страницу? Да, я думал об этом, но насколько правильный такой подход в React?

Comment: его можно собрать и так и сяк, правильно не правильно это не те критерии, удовлетворяет не удовлетворяет Вашим условиям вот что надо оценить, за и против всегда есть, в любом подходе, иначе подход был бы один =)

Comment: Спасибо, друг, я прислушаюсь к тебе. Попробую запилить на react, это вроде модно :)

Comment: если что я его не люблю, и не уговариваю за него, я больше про подход к выбору